# Choose a snippet from the AutoComplete window in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin-studio

I am running Xamarin Studio 4.2.3 on Windows. I have it set to show the autocomplete window automatically when typing... so for instance, when I type cw the following appears:

[image]

The editor will allow me to choose CswWriter from the list and press either *TAB* or *ENTER* to replace the cw with CswWriter.

**However**... it will not allow me to choose the *cw* snippet from the dropdown. I also dug through the Key Bindings dialog looking for the ability to bind something like "Expand Snippet" to a key and did not see it.

Anyone know what's going on? How do I expand the snippet?

I CAN bind a key to "Insert Template...", which pops up another autocomplete-like window with only code snippets in it... but why put them in the normal autocomplete if it won't actually let you choose them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Xamarin Studio has similar behaviour to Visual Studio. To expand the snippet you need to press tab when the completion window is closed.

When you type in cw, the auto-completion window is displayed, pressing tab will then complete the text, in this case cw, which you have already written. Now if you press tab again the code snippet will be expanded.

The first tab key press in your example is a bit confusing since you have already typed in the full text, however for longer code snippet names (e.g. 'prop' and you have typed in just 'pr'), it is less confusing since you will complete the text for the code snippet with the initial tab key press, then pressing tab again will expand it.

Visual Studio displays the message "Press TAB twice to insert the snippet" in the code completion window to make it more obvious what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks... that esplains it!